# How to get sub-string of one line using awk

Tags: unix, awk

```
2012-04-22 04:07:50,862 com.xu.validater[ajp-8009-889]: XU_USER: d888880
2012-04-22 04:07:50,863 com.xu.validater[ajp-8009-888]: XU_USER: d888881
2012-04-22 04:07:50,864 com.xu.validater[ajp-8009-887]: XU_USER: d888882
2012-04-22 04:07:50,865 com.xu.validater[ajp-8009-886]: XU_USER: d888883
...
...
```

I want to get two parts from every line. One is `threadid` like **ajp-8009-889** and the other is `userid` like **d888880**. 
Could you please give me an `awk expression` that can do it ? thanks.

I googled many posts like `awk '{match($0, xxx; print substr($0, a[1, "start"], a[1, "length"])}' xxx.log`. But I cannot solve it. I konw If using java, Matcher.group(x) can do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can work:

```
$ awk -F"[ [\]]" '{print $4,$7}' your_file
```

it indicates that the possible delimiters are `[`, `space` or `]`. Then splits the string based on these delimiters and prints the fields number 4 and 7.

Test:

```
$ awk -F"[ [\]]" '{print $4,$7}' your_file
ajp-8009-889 d888880
ajp-8009-888 d888881
ajp-8009-887 d888882
ajp-8009-886 d888883
```

Comment: Haha @EdMorton  I did not know how to call it and decided to say explode based on the php `explode()` function : )

Comment: "splits" would probably be the right word in this case. In awk the process of splitting the record into fields is called, unsurprisingly, "field splitting", see http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Records.

Comment: I am not only learning programming here in SO, but also English : ) Being a not native English speaker I appreciate any correction, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Set the field separator to be spaces and brackets and print the fourth and seventh field:

```
$ awk -F' |[][]' '{print $4,$7}' file
ajp-8009-889 d888880
ajp-8009-888 d888881
ajp-8009-887 d888882
ajp-8009-886 d888883
```

Comment: Your solution definitely works (+1), but I do not understand why. I assume `-F' |[][]'` means that the separator is `space` or one of the `][` characters. But why the first `]` not needed to be escaped? I tried `-F'[] []'` and `-F'[][ ]'` and they also works. I tried GNU awk's [Using Bracket Expressions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions), but I could not figure out...

Comment: `]` indicates the end of the bracket expression UNLESS it's the first character in which case it's treated as a literal `]`, hence no need to escape it when it's the first character. Not sure why @sudo_O put the space outside of the bracket expression as an "or" for the RE, `[][ ]` or `[] []` would work fine.

Comment: @EdMorton it is just the manifestation of my thought process i.e in my head I thought the `FS` should be a space **or** brackets, after posting I thought `[] []` would be more elegant but thought the edit to be to minor.